# Custom Facebook comment integration (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been tasked with implementing paragraph comments / annotations (like on [Medium](http://medium.com)), however, the client's requirement is that all commenting is performed via Facebook's comment system, so that comments are published to peoples news feeds. Since it has to be "medium style commenting" I do not want to use the default Facebook comment injector - it's pretty ugly and does not meet the requirements.

I have found this great Facebook article on how to *pull* [comments based off an url](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/) using the JS SDK, so now all I need is the ability to post new comments via the JS SDK. I have been trying to figure out [their documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2), but I must admit that it is a bit overwhelming.

Is there anyone here who has experience with posting comments via the JS SDK, who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a `facebook object` for each article, and keep that `object id` so you can "attach" comments to it, making pretty easy to also read the comments per each article.

Code wise, this would be the flow:

When you create an article, [`POST` in your PAGE FEED](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page#publishing) as:

```
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}",,
    "POST",
    {
        "about": "Test about text",
        "hours": "{'mon_1_open': '12:00'}",
        "cover": "1234567890",
       "offset_y": "45"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* response.id will have your post-id */
      }
    }
);
```

Then simple [add comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments/#publish) to that `POST ID` like

```
FB.api(
    "/{post-id}/comments",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test comment"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

to show [all current comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments/#read), just call

```
FB.api(
    "/{post-id}/comments",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

You can even have a new table where you can have `internal_user_id` / `comment_id` to bring all the user comments for your web application...